# Azure authentication when using redundant environments

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, cloud, redundancy

[image: Setup Overview]

Hi,

This is what our setup looks like. We have 2 identical App instances that have dynamically allocated IP & Port, for redundancy. However the problem is when we request authorisation from Azure, we only gain access 50% of the time because the redirect back to the server may or may not be the server that requested authorisation.

Any idea how to solve this, either from Azure side or a basic loaddbalancer that sits in front of the Cloud instances?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Load Balancer supports the following distribution modes for routing connections to instances in the backend pool:

[image: Azure Load Balancer Config Options]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/distribution-mode-concepts